# Dynamic Regular Expression for values in java script

Tags: regex

There is a problem in java script  regular expression .I want my regular expression should be dynamic and it match the string with starting characters.This issue happens in auto complete

Example:

```
var myString = "tester Developer" ;

variable = values which typed in input fields;

var regExp = ('^' + variable + '$');
```

This regExp is change when user type a character.. if user types ' t' (or) 'te' (or) 'tes' ... it returns true. if 'td','ht','fd'(which is not a starting letter of myString) it returns false..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you pass a variable to a Regular Expression JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
var re = new RegExp("ab+c");
```

See this for a more detailed explanation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: how do i check it with my string

Comment: var re = new RegExp("^" + variable + "$");

Comment: It matches only both string are same. but what i want is str1=" tester" str2 ="tes" or str2="te" like this..the match fun returns true for str1 and for given str2's matches... its for auto complete process

Comment: oh. your question is about regular expressions. Not javascript.
var re = new RegExp('^' + variable + '.*$');
i believe.